# Passing array to stringstream

Tags: stringstream, memory-address

This is something I had never noticed but for some reason you can't do something like

```
sstr << myarray;
```

If you do that "sstr" would contain the address of "myarray",You would have to do

```
for(int i;i < sizeof(myarray);i++)
{
sstr << myarray[i];
}
```

I would like to know why does this happens, I don't remember ever having to do that, but personally I think sometimes reality itself changes just to annoy me.

Comment: You didn't even write the declarations of the variables. Or the output you got and that was desired. Trying to reformulate your questions might help it get answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own stream operation for an array to be able to display it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class mydata
{
public:
    mydata(int size = 0) { for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) add(0); }
    ~mydata() { }
    void add(T x) { data.push_back(x); }
    void remove(int pos) { data.erase(data.begin() - pos); }
    T& operator[](int pos) { return data[pos]; }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const mydata<T>& name) {
       for (int i = 0; i < x.data.size(); i++) os << x.data[i] << " "; return os; }
private:
    vector<T> data;
};
```

That would be a standard class for encapsulating your data.  If you wanted to do an operation like `mydata<int> b(8); b[7] = 8;` you can.  The reason the code for the << operator is inside the class is because templates requires typename specific code to be inside the template itself.

Finally, this is how this code can be implemented.

```
int main()
{
    mydata<char> charData;
    mydata<int> intData;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        charData.add(65+i);
        intData.add(i);
    }
    cout << charData << endl;
    cout << intData;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:
`A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T`
     `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19`